# Importing data from two XML parent nodes to a Pandas DataFrame using read_xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I am having trouble in importing an XML file to Pandas where I need to grab data from two parent nodes. One parent node (`AgentID`) has data directly in it, and the other (`Sales`) has child nodes (`Location`, `Size`, `Status`) that contain data, as given below.

```py
test_xml = '''<TEST_XML>
        <Sales>
            <AgentID>0001</AgentID>
            <Sale>
                <Location>0</Location>
                <Size>1000</Size>
                <Status>Available</Status>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <Location>1</Location>
                <Size>500</Size>
                <Status>Unavailable</Status>
            </Sale>
        </Sales>
    </TEST_XML>'''
```

when I try to import this to a Pandas Dataframe below is the only way I was able to grab data under the `Sale` tag.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_xml(test_xml, xpath='//Sale')
```

which gives me a dataframe like the one below:

```
    Location    Size    Status
0   0           1000    Available
1   1           500     Unavailable
```

What I need is including the `AgentID` tag in the DataFrame too, to get the following, but I was unsuccessful. Expected output is given below for clarity:

```
    AgentID     Location    Size    Status
0   0001        0           1000    Available
1   0001        1           500     Unavailable
```

Is there a way to manipulate the `xpath` parameter to include the data inside the `AgentID` tag as well, or is it impossible to do it using Pandas' `read_xml` function? I tried passing a list like `xpath=['//AgentID', '//Sale']` but of course, it did not work...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the expected output is. Can you edit the question, add another `AgentID` and related `Sale`s and the expected output from that?

Comment: I had included the expected DataFrame output, but added the text: "Expected output is given below for clarity" just in case. I basically would like to have the `AgentID` column in the DataFrame, too, but I am not sure if it can be easily achiveable using Pandas' `read_xml` function, because of the way the XML data is structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the desired output using just `read_xml()`; however, it's possible by manipulating it a bit. Essentially, the idea is to get everything from the xml using a generic xpath, select the required columns, populate the `AgentID` column to corresponding to `Sale` columns; then remove redundant rows.

```py
df = pd.read_xml(io.StringIO(test_xml), xpath='//*', dtype=str)[['AgentID', 'Location', 'Size', 'Status']]
df['AgentID'] = df['AgentID'].ffill()
df = df.dropna(how='any').astype({'Location': int, 'Size': int}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image: output]

---

An "easier" solution to get a parent node (although not related to the exact question in the OP) is to convert the XML into a Python dictionary and normalize it into dataframe using `pd.json_normalize`. This works because meta fields (in this case `AgentID`) can be specified here. However, we need to install a third-party library (`xmltodict`) to achieve the first step.

```py
!pip install xmltodict
import xmltodict
df = (
    pd.json_normalize(xmltodict.parse(test_xml)['TEST_XML']['Sales'], 
                      record_path=['Sale'], meta=['AgentID'])
    [['AgentID', 'Location', 'Size', 'Status']]
)
```

Comment: I tried your initial solution and it is the fastest way to do it compared to other responses here, so selecting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), I think nested fields can (or must?) be handled by style sheets with [xlst 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/).

So, you can try making a simple template where [`for-each`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#for-each) nested `Sale`, you [`copy-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copy-of) the value and place it right after its corresponding `AgentID` :

```py
ss = """
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Sales/Sale">
        <outputData>
          <AgentID><xsl:value-of select="//Sales/AgentID"/></AgentID>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </outputData>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
"""

from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_xml(StringIO(test_xml),
    stylesheet=StringIO(ss), dtype={"AgentID": str}
)
```

Output :

```py
print(df)

  AgentID  Location  Size       Status
0    0001         0  1000    Available
1    0001         1   500  Unavailable

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: when I try to run your code I get the following error: `TypeError: read_xml() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'`

Comment: [`dtype` was added in 1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#read-xml-now-supports-dtype-converters-and-parse-dates) and I'm using the latest pandas version (`2.1.3`).

Comment: I upgraded Pandas and I confirm the code works. However, it is quite slow unfortunately. It takes a second to run the read_xml function without the stylesheet argument. Once I include it, it takes forever to complete (15 minutes and still running for a 700,000 line XML file)

Comment: @marillion, this XSLT can be rewritten to avoid full document search using `//`. Try this XSLT: https://pastebin.com/aZrheTvV.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it with `read_xml()` in this case. I would use a more manual approach - parse with lxml and load into pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(test_xml)

cols = ["AgentID",     "Location",    "Size",    "Status"]
rows = []
sales = doc.xpath('//Sales')
for sale in sales:    
    for s in sale.xpath('.//Sale'):
        row = [sale.xpath('.//AgentID/text()')[0]]
        row.extend(s.xpath('.//*/text()'))
        rows.append(row)

pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

That should give you your expected output.

Comment: Thanks, this also works nicely, but not as fast as the accepted answer.